# Notepad++ Find and replace dots with commas using regular expression

Tags: notepad++

I have some text in a file:

```
25968.254.000.1234.784.000000000000.85  8547968.82  0   874968.21   5896314.42
```

I want to find only this part:

```
25968.254.000.1234.784.000000000000.85  8547968.82
```

Which I know I can do using this regexp:

```
^\d{5}\.(\d{3})\.\d{3}\.(\d{4})\.\d{3}\.(\d{12})\.\d{2}\s([0-9.]*)\s
```

What I want to do is replace the full-stops `.` in the first part with commas `,` and end up with this:

```
25968,254,000,1234,784,000000000000,85  8547968.82
```

How do I go about that?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have made a few changes to your question, mainly in formatting, showing data (lines of text from the file and expected result) and regexs in `code` format (accessed using the `{}` symbol above the editing pane). I've also done a little work clarifying the question to make it easier to understand. Please see the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use regex [capture-groups](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html).

You wrap each digit group in ( ) then reference them using \N where N is the Nth group.

Use this for FIND:

```
^(\d{5}).(\d{3}).(\d{3}).(\d{4}).(\d{3}).(\d{12}).(\d{2})\s([0-9.]*)\s
```

Then this for REPLACE:

```
\1,\2,\3,\4,\5,\6,\7 \8
```

Answer (score 0):

This will replace dot with comma if it is after some digits only, from the beginning of line untill it founds a non digit character. It works for any number of digit-dot.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^|\G)(\d+)\.`
- Replace with: `$1,`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:         : start non capture group
    ^       : beginning of line
  |         : OR
    \G      : restart from last match
)           : end group
(\d+)       : group 1, 1 or more digits
\.          : a dot
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          : content of group 1 (i.e. the digits)
,           : a comma
```

**Result for given example:**

```
25968,254,000,1234,784,000000000000,85  8547968.82  0   874968.21   5896314.42
```